# Installing VIM through MacPorts gives an error

Tags: vim, macports, darwin

I was trying to install VIM with the ruby package through macports, by executing the command:

> sudo port install vim +ruby +huge

It seems the package was downloaded fine, but an error occurred. This is the end of the log file. Perhaps somebody can shed any light on the causes?

```
info:build Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
:info:build   "_rb_num2uint", referenced from:
:info:build       _window_set_cursor in if_ruby.o
:info:build ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
:info:build collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
:info:build lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc3hoDmr.out (No such file or directory)
:info:build make[1]: *** [vim] Error 1
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_editors_vim/vim/work/vim73/src'
:info:build make: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_editors_vim/vim/work/vim73'
:info:build shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_editors_vim/vim/work/vim73" && /usr/bin/make -j5 -w all " returned error 2
:error:build Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:build Backtrace: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: the following items did not execute (for vim): org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:build Log for vim is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_editors_vim/vim/main.log
```

I'm running Darwin (OSX Lion) with the latest MacPorts.

Comment: the binaries from http://code.google.com/p/macvim/ are not an option for you?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling it for the right architecture? I'd guess you probably want to compile the x86_64 version if you're on a somewhat new computer.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272999/install-ruby-support-for-vim-on-mac-os-x

citation from here:

```
MacVim is a very Mac-friendly version of Vim, and it's got Ruby support already built in. It can be used as both a GUI and Terminal application. (Check out :help macvim-start from within MacVim for details.)
```

Also it provides terminal version to use.

Comment: Thank you, as a beginner, I was under the impression that all the packages MacPorts lists work under Darwin.

Comment: Many things in Mac OS X are from FreeBSD

Comment: What OS are you using? Darwin or Mac OS X? All the non-aqua MacPorts packages are supposed to work in both OSes. Could it be that your problem comes from a library imported from an old G5 based machine? If the CLI Vim found in MacVim's bundle doesn't work (it may be expecting Mac OS X specifically, I don't know) you may try to remove ruby completely from your machine (include gems) then try again with `$ sudo port install vim +huge +ruby`. MacPorts will take care of all the dependencies including ruby and use the correct flags. Why not a Linux or BSD distro instead?

Comment: @romainl can you give link to Darwin OS distribution you mean? I use Mac OS X Lion, which Andres is using too.

Comment: I don't have a link at hand but I think it's officially dead since a long time. I remember toying with it 5 or 6 years ago and ultimately deciding it was useless to me. I didn't bring Darwin into this though: Andres introduced it by writing that he uses Darwin which may a) be a useless information since all versions of Mac OS X are based on Darwin anyway or b) be an important info because a standalone Darwin lacks a **lot** of what makes Mac OS X.

Comment: Sure you're right! And MacPorts designed for Mac OS X mostly last time. I've been having same issues with building vim from MacPorts before I haven't found MacVim